# regex match get first match

Tags: regex

I'm working with existing code where regular expressions are used to parse HTML. For specific reasons it is not possible to use XPATH. The HTML is actually a html/text email. In the email I have multiple div elements with text content. I'm trying to write regex which match n-th div element. Unfortunatelly these div elements do not have any attributes like classes or ids. I tried this but it match all occurrences

```
<div>(.*)<\/div>{1}
```

There many suggestions out there but none of theme is working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You may wanna post example data/or string

Comment: <body>

                <div><a href=3D'http://longurl.com?fvklfdnkvf jvfdsvjldsfvdsfv</b>=
</a></div>

                <div>John Doe</div>

                <div>name@site.com</div>

                </div>

           =20

Comment: I need to get the second div here is a live example http://regexr.com/3fosg

Comment: Your `{1}` is only applying to the `>`. Making the `.*` non-greedy would probably help add a `?`, e.g. `<div>(.*?)<\/div>`. A parser would probably be a better approach. Where are you using this?